# dataframe to JSON conversion

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that i need to convert to JSON. The data currently looks like

```
                       text     ids
0                 add a car     None
1                         None  695f1
2                         None  a86b5c
3  add another car to my log    None
4                         None  1ba0
5                  Concerts     None
6                         None  a4f7
7                         None  fea
8                         None  410
```

I need the JSON dict to look something like this and ignore the none

```
{
  "text": "add a car",
  "ids": [
    "695f1",
    "a86b5c"
  ]
}
```

The steps I have are:

Figured it out.

first set NaN Values where None

```
df1 = df1.fillna(value=np.nan)
```

Fill with NaN with previous known value

```
df1['text'] = df['text'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Drop NaN

```
df1 = df1.dropna()
```

convert to json

```
df1.to_json('temp.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

The problem I have is the format appears incorrect. I am seeing

```
{"text":"add a car","ids":" 695f1"}
{"text":"add a car","ids":"a86b5c"}
{"text":"add another car to my log","ids":"1ba0"}
{"text":"Concerts","ids":"a4f7"}
```

I want :

```
    {
  "text": "add a car", 
  "ids": 
    [
      "695f1", 
      "a86b5c"
    ]
  
}
{
  "text": "add another car to my log", 
  "ids": 
    [
      "1ba0", 
    ], 
 
}
{
"text": "Concerts", 
  "ids": 
    [
      "a4f7", 
      "fea",
      "410",
    ]
}
```

Comment: SO is a place where you should ask question about problems that you have. Not seeking people that will do the work for you. For more information regarding the way a question should be made, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post edited. I posted before i had the example correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close, need aggregate `list` first:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].ffill()
df = df.dropna()

df1 = df.groupby('text', sort=False).agg(list).reset_index()
print (df1)
                        text               ids
0                  add a car   [695f1, a86b5c]
1  add another car to my log            [1ba0]
2                   Concerts  [a4f7, fea, 410]

df1.to_json('temp.json', orient='records')
```